# Ubuntu 17.10 won't recognize HDMI cable

Tags: hdmi, 17.10

I recently did a clean install on my PC of Ubuntu 17.10 and ever since then HDMI won't work. I can connect a cable, but Ubuntu won't recognize it. Oddly, the TV does. It's not a "smart" TV per se but it does inform me that this is an "unsupported mode" because the "resolution isn't supported by this television" (That's not an exact phrasing, I'm translating it to English).

Of course it has nothing to do with resolution, Ubuntu isn't even recognizing the other monitor (`xrandr` doesn't even show any possible output besides the built-in screen). I know the cable works, and this problem also happened with a different television. Also, previous versions of Ubuntu on the same computer worked fine with HDMI so even though I have no idea why this is happening, **I know for sure it's because of the 17.10 update**.

What do I do?

**update**
I tried rebooting while HDMI was still connected and now it works perfectly. What the hell? How do I set it up so I don't have to reboot for it to recognize the other monitor?

Comment: It should be noted I'm using a Propriety driver, the same one as used when this PC had Ubuntu 17.04 and it worked fine. Not that it should matter but the laptop is a Fujitsu A512 model

Comment: Actually your hardware specifications matter a lot and what drivers you're using even more. Now, what proprietary drivers exactly? For what hardware exactly? Graphics + graphics drivers play a huge part in everything video related, of course, but it can't be it because your model has Intel Graphics and Intel drivers aren't proprietary?!? Please [edit] your question and add all the relevant information there instead of comments.

Comment: @MichaelBay Where have I said that intel drivers aren't proprietary? I think I actually said the opposite.

Comment: *It should be noted I'm using a Propriety driver**... Intel graphics drivers ARE open source. Now read the above comment again so you may understand the confusion.

Comment: @MichaelBay If I connect the cable and reboot, HDMI works fine. Previous versions of Ubuntu also recognized the cable fine. It's only when connecting the cable while Ubuntu is running that I have problems. Does that not show that the problem is with the newer version rather than the driver?